# Calculation of Load Impedance of three phase Inverter

Tags: pwm, impedance, inverter, load, losses

Could anyone here please assist me how the Equivalent impedance of Load of three phase inverter is calculated from the Inverter parameters shown in below screenshot? This screenshot is tutorial example of PSIM for calculation of Losses "Altair PSIM Tutorial / IGBT and MOSFET Loss Calculation in the Thermal Module" What I can see in this tutorial, the parameters taken for three phase inverter is below:
Vdc=450V
Carrier Frequency= 8kHz
Modulation Frequency= 60Hz
Modulation Index:0.842
Power Factor: 0.8 Lagging
Output voltage: 230V
Power: 20kW

[image]